# Dynamic values inside the mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I am trying to get result using below query, idRegion is recorded in database as 1,2,3,4 for each franchisee, so what I want is to display all franchisees with idRegion 2. I am getting idRegion via $_Get. this display only first digit before coma, I think so it should ready whole string 1,2,3,4 ? When I am working with static values that works?

```
$colname_franchisee = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $colname_franchisee = $_GET['id'];
}


$query_franchisee = sprintf("SELECT * FROM franchise WHERE stiShowInLinks = 'Y' AND idRegion LIKE '%s%' ORDER BY stiName ASC", $colname_franchisee);
```

Comment: `$_GET['id'])` gives you `1` when it should be `1,2,3,4`? Then there must be something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: no, I am getting value $_GET = 2 from URL and then I should search string 1,2,3,4 inside the database and when this string contains 2 it should display franchisee name, but at this moment only displaying all the queries with $_GET = 1

Comment: this have something definitely to do with '%%%%s%%%%%'

Comment: as if I so idRegion LIKE '%2%' than it works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work although I do not like your database design:

```
$query_franchisee = sprintf("
    SELECT *
    FROM franchise
    WHERE
    stiShowInLinks = 'Y' AND (
        idRegion = '%d' OR
        idRegion LIKE '%d,%%' OR
        idRegion LIKE '%%,%d' OR
        idRegion LIKE '%%,%d,%%'
    )
    ORDER BY stiName ASC
",
$colname_franchisee,
$colname_franchisee,
$colname_franchisee,
$colname_franchisee
);
```

The sprintf function treats the `%` character as a format specifier and treats at the next few characters in a special way. In order to use the `%` character literally, you must use `%%`. So after sprintf, your query becomes:

```
idRegion = '1234' OR
idRegion LIKE '1234,%' OR
idRegion LIKE '%,1234' OR
idRegion LIKE '%,1234,%'
```

Comment: Whoops. There are *4* possible cases. Don't forget to check the revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$colname_franchisee = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $cf = intval($_GET['id']);  only if id integer.

}
$query_franchisee = "SELECT * FROM franchise 
                     WHERE stiShowInLinks = 'Y' 
                       AND idRegion LIKE '%cf%' 
                     ORDER BY stiName ASC", $cf);
```